# React modal element doesn't cover the left part of the screen

Tags: react-native, react-modal

I have a `Modal` element that I want on the whole screen, to do that I created the functions `widthPercentageToDP` and `heightPercentageToDP` that get the width and height from the device and fills it according to the percentage set, the height is covered completely but with the width there is a small gap to the left that is not covered.

```
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, PixelRatio } from 'react-native';

                  <Modal isVisible={true}>
                        <View style={[s.contract]}                                 > 
                                <View >
                                    <Text>
                                        I want the modal on the whole screen
                                    </Text>
                                </View>
                                <View >
                                    {previousButton}{nextButton}
                                </View>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    contract: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        width: widthPercentageToDP('100%'),
        height: heightPercentageToDP('100%')
    }
});

const widthPercentageToDP = widthPercent => {
  const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const elemWidth = parseFloat(widthPercent);
  return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(screenWidth * elemWidth / 100);
};
const heightPercentageToDP = heightPercent => {
  const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
  const elemHeight = parseFloat(heightPercent);
return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(screenHeight * elemHeight / 100);
};
```

[image]
This is the screenshot on my simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the `margin` of the `modal` element to 0

```
         <Modal style={{margin: 0}} isVisible={true}>
                        ...
         </Modal>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use css?
Give your **Modal component** the *modal* css-class and define the latter as:

```
.modal {
  background:white;
  box-shadow:0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0, 0.26)
  width:90%;
  position: fixed;
  top:20vh;
  left:5%;
}
media (min-width:768px) {
  .modal {
    width: 50rem;
    left:calc((100%-50rem) / 2)
  }
}
```

Here is a not yet finished but **working** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-in-react-6nz1l)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give height and width values to cover the screen. A simple `flex: 1` will do.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    contract: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        flex: 1, // <---
    }
});
```

Comment: with `flex:1` I get also a gap at the top, bottom and right

Comment: unless you're using `SafeAreaView`, `flex: 1` should cover the whole screen.

Comment: I'm using `SafeAreaView ` but If I remove it it only affects the permanent content (the one that's hidden when the `modal` is `true`), not the `modal` element

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the location of your modal in document flow because it might limit the scope of your modal background. I experienced a similar problem where the modal didn't cover the top of the page and changing the position of the modal element solved the problem Hope it works for you as well.